# Does Spark SQL support float literals like 1.0f?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark SQL is documented to accept float literals such as `0.0f` or `1e0f`, and double literals like `0.0d` or `1e0d`.

However, while double literals are accepted, Spark seems to interpret the point in float literals like an object lookup and complains, for example on `0.0f`, that `0` (on the left of the decimal point) is not a struct.

The only workaround I found for now is `CAST (0.0d AS FLOAT)` instead of `0.0f`.

In tutorials, while f is listed as a possible suffix, no example uses them. Could it be an overlook in the Spark SQL feature support, or is there something I am missing?

I am using Spark 3.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `f` to indicate floating precision is a new feature in Spark 3.1. You can compare the documentations:

1. Spark 3.0.2: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/sql-ref-literals.html#fractional-literals
2. Spark 3.1.1: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/sql-ref-literals.html#fractional-literals

So you cannot use this feature in Spark 3.0.2, and you will need to use `cast(0.0 as float)`.